# Double group by in multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, group-by, sum

I have three joined tables.

```
select * 
from Ordering 
inner join Client on client.id=ordering.client_id 
inner join Dish on ordering.dish_id=dish.id
```

[image]

I would like sum `quantity` column and group by `name_dish` and later  `client_id`.

Now I made it but it is not enough (for one client):

```
select client.familyName, client.name, client.phone, sum(ordering.quantity),dish.name_dish 
from Ordering 
inner join Client on client.id=ordering.client_id 
inner join Dish on ordering.dish_id=dish.id 
where ordering.client_id=1 
group by (dish.name_dish)
```

[image]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using. I suspect this is MySQL (otherwise your `group by` query would fail).

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your existing query, you need to put all `select`ed columns that are not within an aggregate function in the `group by` clause (that is, all columns excepted `quantity`). I would also suggest including the primary keys of the `client` and `dish` table, in case two clients (resp. dishes) have the same name.

Consider the following aggregate query:

```
select c.family_name, c.name, c.phone, sum(o.quantity) sum_quantity, d.name_dish
from ordering o
inner join client c on c.id = o.client_id 
inner join dish d on o.dish_id = d.id
group by c.client_id, c.family_name, c.name, c.phone, d.id, d.name_dish
```

Some databases (actually, Postgres) are content with just the primary keys of the two tables in the `group by` clause:

```
select c.family_name, c.name, c.phone, sum(o.quantity) sum_quantity, d.name_dish
from ordering o
inner join client c on c.id = o.client_id 
inner join dish d on o.dish_id = d.id
group by c.client_id, d.id
```